# pysearch-masterを導入したいのですが、pymongoでエラーが出ます。

Tags: python, mongodb, beautifulsoup

以前の投稿で、[`QtWebKit`の画像や動画を見られるようにするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47854/qtwebkit%E3%81%A7%E7%94%BB%E5%83%8F%E3%82%84%E5%8B%95%E7%94%BB%E3%82%92%E8%A6%8B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%81%AF)という質問を出し、ご指摘を受けましたので質問を分ける事にしました。

**したいこと**
　Google検索エンジンなどのように、文字などを適当なラインにいれれば、検索候補を出してくれるようなものを自分のアプリに備え付けたいと思っています。現在`QtWebKit`で、簡易的なブラウザを作っていて、ここに装着するようにしたいです。
**見付けた手がかり**
　[自分のパソコンでpython検索エンジンを動かしたい！](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/38146/%E8%87%AA%E5%88%86%E3%81%AE%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%81%A7-python%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%92%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

質問を出してしまってからこの質問の存在に気づいたので、以前の質問よりは大幅に内容を変更しました。ですが、これと同じような仕組みを導入したいので、これと全く同じものを、とにかく備え付けてみようと考えました。（なお、自分はまだこれを備え付けた事がないので、どれほどのものかはわからないのですが・・・。多分調べても、これ以上のものは見つからないと思います。）
**二の舞**
　そこで、このコードを実行してみようと思い、ダウンロードをして導入して、crawler.pyを実行してみると、私も、このようなエラーが起きてしまいました。

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MONGO_URL'
```

そこで、リンク先にあるように、`from ..config import MONGO_URL`
と打ってみました。
すると、

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

となりました。
　リンク先の質問では、ここはうまくいっていたように思えたのですが、自分ではこのようなエラーが発生してしまったのです。
　リンク先の回答では、

```
MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
```

とするように書いてあったのでそうしてみました。それで上記のようなエラーが出ます。
要は、このMONGO_URLの名前を別の空間から取得したいのだろうと思ったものですから、

```
try:
    from config import MONGO_URL
except ImportError as e:
    MONGO_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
```

モジュール的な段階を完全に無視して、直接同一モジュール内で、MONGO_URLに値を入れ込んでやりました。ここで何かを大きく間違えた気がしていますが、（製作者の意図に沿わない方法なのではないかと考えています。）そのうえで、再度crawler.pyを実行してみました。
　エラーは全く発生しませんでしたが、その代わり、何も発生しませんでした。（トップモジュールではないからですね。）
**私の経験値**
`bs4,janome,pymongo,urllib.request,requests,config,argparse,flask`

**全て使った経験がありません。**経験値０です。レベル１でロマリアに行く感じ。
しかし、質問者が、ここで、`python manage.py crawler`
とコマンドを打っておられるのを看まして、自分も見様見真似で、同じようにしてみました。
すると、

```
F:\pysearch-master>python manage.py crawler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 12, in <module>
    crawl_web('http://docs.sphinx-users.jp/contents.html', 2)
  File "F:\pysearch-master\web_crawler\crawler.py", line 72, in crawl_web
    add_page_to_index(page_url, html)
  File "F:\pysearch-master\web_crawler\crawler.py", line 60, in add_page_to_index
    add_to_index(word, url)
  File "F:\pysearch-master\web_crawler\crawler.py", line 41, in add_to_index
    entry = col.find_one({'keyword': keyword})
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\collection.py", line 1262, in find_one
    for result in cursor.limit(-1):
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1189, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1087, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1558, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1511, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1544, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 427, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "C:\Users\***\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 199, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [WinError 10061] 対象のコンピューターによって拒否されたため、接続できませんでした。
```

---

一体何が起きているのでしょうか？
素直な初見では、階層構造がよくわからないし、製作者の意図がわからなかったです。

1.`config`モジュールが別階層で２つ存在している点。
2.`web_crawler`モジュールから、`collection`の名前を呼び出しているのに、
 `web_crawler`モジュール内に、`collection`という名前のファイルが存在しない点。
（私は、`web_crawler`というモジュール(このpysearch-masterに元々あるやつではないもの）を、インストールしました。これと同じモジュールが`conda install`できたからです。しかし、製作者は個人で同じ名前のモジュールを作成しています。そのどちらにも、`collection`という名前はなかったのですが・・・。）
3.**name** == "**main**"コードが、`manage.py`と、`drop_collection.py`の
両方に存在しているため、どちらをトップレベルのモジュールとして想定していたのかが私からは判断しにくかったということ。
4.`drop_connection`モジュールの中で、`url_parse`という定義されていない変数が普通に使われていること。

5.`col`を、`collection as col`として呼び出しているのに、その後にすぐ、`col = ...`という形で、名前を生成し、変数をいれこんでいること。
6.後、`conda install config`も出来た気がします。

私よりもずっとレベルが高い人が書いたコードでしょうから、謎が多いのですが、全てのモジュールの外観を最低でもつかむ必要があるかもしれません。しかし、既に解決済みの質問をなぞっていくとできるかなと思ったのですが、やはりそんな甘いものではありませんでした。コードの全体量は、合わせてもせいぜい１００行程度なのですが・・・。

---

```
Windows-10 

python3.6.3
```

Comment: 「Google検索エンジンを搭載する」というのはどういうことですか？

Comment: @mjy 突っ込みをいただいたので少し返事を考えていたのですが、ひょっとしてこういうのはウェブクローリングや、スクレーピングというのでしょうか？右にpython検索エンジンを動かしたいという質問がありますが、結果としてそのようになってほしいと思います。とすれば、重複でしょうか。要は、検索機能をつけたいということなのです。

Comment: 例えば Chrome や Firefox などのブラウザにはアドレスバーや検索ボックスなどといった UI 要素があり、そこに検索ワードを入力すると Google などの検索サイトに移動しますが、そういったことでは無く、あくまで自前で検索エンジンを実装する話ということで大丈夫ですか？

Comment: @mjy はい。どのような手段であれ、pythonで検索機能を実装させたいということです。

Comment: なるほど。では、求めているのはGoogleのサーチエンジンのようなWebページに対する全文検索機能を持つプログラムということですね。
大きく分けると、Webページを巡回して検索対象のデータを集めてくるクローラーと、集めたデータを検索するための全文検索エンジンで構成することになると思います。
そういったものを探していることが解り易いように質問を編集すれば、ある程度回答が得られそうな気がします。
ただ、「QtWebKitで」という部分はどういったイメージなのかよく解らないです。

Comment: @mjy　なるほど。指摘いただいたことを踏まえたうえで更新してみます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

上記の検索エンジン実装に際し、何ら経験がないようでしたら、
この実装を試みられてはいかがでしょうか。

[Whoosh](https://whoosh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html)

pure Pythonで書かれているライブラリで、高速な検索が可能です。
元々の質問が検索エンジンの搭載が目的であるならば、このライブラリが役に立つと思います。
他のわからないライブラリ群については、おいおい勉強していくといいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。検討してみます。